# Unable to correctly use ethers.js to call batch permit function

Tags: ethers.js, coinbase, permit

I was playing around with ethers.js and the coinbase wallet sdk, and I'm not sure if I'm using the ether interface api correctly. Right now I'm trying to call permit batch, but whenever I attempt to sign the transaction, it defaults to an insanely high network fee and the preview from the coinbase wallet extension indicates that I have insufficient funds. This is the gist of the code I'm running, the abi is the [permit2 protocol](https://etherscan.io/address/0x000000000022d473030f116ddee9f6b43ac78ba3#code). Any help would be much appreciated.

```
const signTransaction = async() => {

      let nonce;
      let signer;
      try{
          signer = await web3.getSigner();
          nonce  = await web3.getTransactionCount(signer.address);
      }
      catch(e){
          console.log("Error retrieving nonce", e);
          alert(e);
          return;
      }

      const permitBatch = {
          details: [
              {
                  token: "0x7d2768dE32b0b80b7a3454c06BdAc94A69DDc7A9", // AAVE
                  amount: 1,
                  expiration: toDeadline(/* 30 days= */ 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24),
                  nonce: nonce,
              }
          ],
          spender: "0x7d2768dE32b0b80b7a3454c06BdAc94A69DDc7A9",
          sigDeadline: toDeadline(1000 * 60 * 60),
      }


      try{
          const { domain, types, values } = AllowanceTransfer.getPermitData(permitBatch, 
                                                                            PERMIT2_ADDRESS, 
                                                                            1)
          const signature = await (signer).signTypedData(domain, types, values)


          const contract = new ethers.Interface(permit2ABI)
          

          const contractInterface = contract.interface
          const targetMethod = 'permit(address,((address,uint160,uint48,uint48)[],address,uint256),bytes)'
          const data = contract.encodeFunctionData(targetMethod,
              [
                  signer.address,
                  permitBatch,
                  signature
              ]
          )
          const signed = await signer.signTransaction({
              nonce,
              from: signer.address,
              to: "0x000000000022D473030F116dDEE9F6B43aC78BA3",
              data, 
          })
      }
      catch(e){
          console.log(e)
      }
  }
```

Comment: i'm facing the same issue but with web3js, i tried multiple solution (self suggeset :P), tried mimicing a tulipe but always get an error, in web3js it says undefined check function when debuggin its the function that check for abi params, here is my code (simplified): const permit2Contract = new web3.eth.Contract(Permit2ContractABI, Permit2ContractAddress); const permitDetails = [[["0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2", 5000000000000000, deadline, nonce],["0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7", 8214487, deadline, nonce]], initiator, deadline] const permitData = permit2Contract.met